# Images imported to Illustrator get resized despite their original size

Tags: adobe-illustrator, images, resize

I have a folder full of pictures, they are all 6000x4000 images. However, when I impor them into Illustrator (drag&drop inside the app) their size changes, their width and height sometimes is half of what they are, sometimes they are correct.

I'm thinking that probably something is wrong with the images, but I can't find out what.

I assume this also happens in Photoshop, didn't try it yet.

Comment: What's the original resolution of the images (PPI)?

Comment: Another indicator is to view the files in Windows Explorere / Finder (Mac) and sort by file size. See if the file size is different for any of the images.

Comment: The DIP varies wildly, also the size, some images are 1.5MB and others are 20+. However, they are all still 6000x4000. Seems like I'm missing something.

Comment: Illustrator imports raster images at their set PPI. If you want all the images to import at the same size, they need to all be the same PPI *and* dimensions. You can transform them within Illustrator but Illustrator does *not* perform any interpolation on raster images. Which means, scaling images within Illustrator *may* result in lower quality (especially when up-scaling).

Comment: Dont worry file size on disk has a supprisingly weak correlation with pixel dimensions when it  comes to cmpressed files.

Comment: It's 2022. There's still no ACTUAL answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Illustrator imports raster images at their set PPI.

If you want all the images to import at the same size, they need to all be the same PPI and dimensions.

You can transform them within Illustrator but Illustrator does not perform any interpolation on raster images. Which means, scaling images within Illustrator may result in lower quality (especially when up-scaling).

Answer (score 1):

What is the file type of the pictures you are importing? If they are JPGs they could have varying quality levels would could affect file size.

The pixels per inch setting should be the same for each image for them to all be the same size when you import them into an Illustrator file. Open the images in Photoshop and select **Image › Image Size** to adjust those settings. If you have to  change the PPI number, make sure you uncheck 'resample" before entering a new number. After they all share the same PPI, save them and try re-importing them into Illustrator.